# Sign in with facebook does not redirect to app on iOS, instead display blank page. Expo, Facebook,

Tags: firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-authentication

Everything have been woking prior to issue appeared. Now without touching anything sign in with facebook no longer work on iOS and instead of redirecting back to app a blank page is shown.

Tried uninstalling and sign out/in from the Facebook app. Works as usual on android.

Expo version: 3.17.18
Facebook: expo-facebook @8.0.0

The screen which physical ios devices are stuck on:

[image: facebook-redirect-issue]

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';

Facebook.initializeAsync("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "APP")
  // appId from Facebook Developer Console; const appId = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  const appId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  // Permissions required, consult Facebook docs
  const permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];  

  const {
    type,
    token,
  } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
    appId,
    {permissions}
  );

  switch (type) {
    case 'success': {
      // Set persistent auth state
      await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
      // Sign in with Facebook credential
      const facebookProfileData = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
      // Do something with Facebook profile data  
      console.log(facebookProfileData)
      // OR you have subscribed to auth state change, authStateChange handler will process the profile data
      return Promise.resolve({type: 'success'}).then(navigateNext);
    }
    case 'cancel': {
      return Promise.reject({type: 'cancel'});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On facebook go to:

Settings > Download Your Information > Create File

Somehow downloading that file fixed the white screen of death issue.